# Deriving exponential distribution from sum of two squared normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribuition $\mathcal{N}(0,1/2)$ and $Z = X^2 + Y^2$. I'd like to prove based on $X$ and $Y$ pdf's that $Z$ has exponential distribuition.

Comment: Hint: convert the integral to polar coordinates, where $Z$ becomes the square of the radius.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First use the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ and switch to polar coordinates, then
$$ \mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(X^2+Y^2\leq z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x^2+y^2\leq z}e^{-x^2-y^2}\;dxdy=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{z}}e^{-r^2}r\;drd\theta$$
$$=2\int_0^{\sqrt{z}}re^{-r^2}\;dr $$
Now if we set $u=r^2$ then we get
$$ \mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)=\int_0^ze^{-u}\;du$$

so $Z$ is exponentially distributed with rate parameter $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: How do we know the joint CDF of $X^2$ and $Y^2$?

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are IID, their joint PDF is the product of each PDF, that is, $f_{XY} = f_X \cdot f_Y.$

Answer (score 4):

$Z$ has a chi-square distribution with the number of degrees of freedom to make it the special case of the exponential. Here $X$ and $Y$ are required to be independent.

Comment: Just edited to add that they are i.i.d.

Comment: This post merely restates the result.  The question asks to show *how* this is the case using the distribution functions.

Comment: @whuber But Michael Chernick's answer is what you once described to me re another question as a _statistician's_ answer  (in contrast to the answer that I had given to the question which you characterized as a mathematician's (or probabilist's) answer. So why is Michael Chernick's answer put down as a mere restatement of the result to be proved? To my mind, it is the perfect statistician's answer.

Comment: @Dilip I suppose that in some cases the distinctions between "why," "what," and "how" might be subtle.  In this particular instance, the context of the question--with particular reference to its explicit request to use pdfs--makes it clear to me that this post, although it's partially correct, is not responsive.